# jquery gurus, jquery extend is not cloning the dom elements

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

Here is the [jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/cooolbasha/umKHd/1/):

```
class Overlay
    constructor: ->
      @header = $("<div> header</div>")
      @footer = $("<div> footer</div>")      
    get: ->
      @popup = $("<div></div>").append(@header).append(@footer)
      @popup.clone(true)

overlay = new Overlay
overlay_extend = {}    
$.extend(true,overlay_extend,overlay)
overlay_extend.header.append("<div>more header</div>")  
overlay.header.appendTo("body")
```

In the jsfiddle I changed the extended dom element and the orginal dom is changed..Any new ideas.

Comment: jQuery only clones plain object or arrays but not DOM elements (and probably not jQuery objects either). [Here is the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L303).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $.extend is not meant to work on instances of a class, though I can't find any mention of it in the DOCS. The docs simply mentions that primitive types aren't extended. Also, extending with a plain object that contains references to dom elements will result in the new object containing references to the same dom elements, not clones of those dom elements. This is by design.

Comment: @KevinB - what do you mean by design..why should it be that way

Comment: The purpose of the jQuery.extend method is to merge the contents of one object into another. It does not clone objects, it creates new objects that have the same properties of other objects or it adds the properties of one object to an existing object.

Comment: @KevinB: A common use of `extend` is `var copy = $.extend(true, {}, oldObject);`, which does clone objects (prototypes notwithstanding).

Comment: @josh3736 I guess that depends on what you consider a clone. It takes the properties from oldObject and makes them properties of the new object. If one of those properties are a reference to something else, such as a dom object or an instance of a class, that reference is preserved. http://jsfiddle.net/uhXrV/ acting on the "clone" or "copy" created by $.extend acts on the original object that is being referenced.

Comment: @KevinB, I guess that should be phrased as "it clones POJOs".  Dealing with the DOM is another issue, which is why this question exists.  (However, in a deep copy, it shouldn't matter if something is "an instance of a class" since JS has no such thing as classes; it's just another object that gets duplicated.)

Answer (score 4):

`extend` only clones native JS objects, not DOM elements.  Here, the cloned jQuery object still points to the original DOM element.

You need to [`.clone()`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=clone) the DOM elements.

Comment: I know there is clone method..I am looking for solution to clone the object irrespective of JS/Dom

Comment: There's nothing built in, you'll have to write your own.

Comment: could not this be a standard thing..or should I hack the extend method in jquery to check if it is dom call the clone method on it...I know the clone method works very well(deep as well)

Comment: I wouldn't hack `$.extend` because you might break other code -- other parts of jQuery, plugins, etc.  Instead, write your own function.  As a general function, you could use jQuery's `extend` to clone the POJO, then loop over the object and check each element for `.jquery`, and if it exists, use `clone`.  However, this would be slow.  It's a better idea to add a clone method to your `Overlay` that clones itself (`var r = $.extend({}, this)`) and then sets `r.header = r.header.clone()` and `r.footer = r.footer.clone()`, then `return r`.