# jQuery deep copy still holds reference to original object

Tags: jquery, deep-copy

I am using jQuery's (v2.1.1) extend function to create a deep copy of an object expecting that the copy will not hold any reference to the original. However, when I make changes to the original, they also are reflected in the copy. For example, both `original` and `copy` will have the new child node after this function is completed.

```
    var copy = $.extend(true, {}, original);
    try {
        var parent= $(copy).children('parent');     
        parent = parent.get(0);

        var newNode = $('<child/>');
        $(parent).append(newNode);
        ...
    }
    catch(err) {
        return original;
    }
    return copy;
```

Is this expected and how can I create a distinct copy?

Comment: If original is the results of a jquery match, why not just use clone instead?

Comment: @RobertMoskal I read that clone() will only copy DOM elements. The original object has functions that need to be copied as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery gurus, jquery extend is not cloning the dom elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639836/jquery-gurus-jquery-extend-is-not-cloning-the-dom-elements)